# In-Memory DB Compression factor: How to calculate?

Tags: compression, hana, in-memory-database

I've answered 5, but the correct answer is actually 20. I just don't know how it calculates to 20!

How can calculate it exactly?

[image]

This's an example by "Hasso Plattner Institut"

[image]

If this question is not suitable for SO, please direct me to the correct SE site.

Comment: This is not a programming question...

Comment: Have you considered dba.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 1):

Simplifications (as used by HPI in their examples):

```
1KB = 1000B
1MB = 1000KB
```

To calculate the size of the uncompressed dictionary, use the sum of the size of each field and multiply by the number of rows:

```
(49+49+1+1)*50 000 000 = ~5000 MB
```

Now calculate the smallest number of bits that the number of unique values of each column can be represented as and round it up:

```
Name:    CEILING(Log2(2000))   = 15
Surname: CEILING(Log2(100000)) = 17
Age:     CEILING(Log2(128))    = 7
Gender:  CEILING(Log2(2))      = 1
```

The size of the total attribute vector is the number is as follows:

```
(15+17+7+1)*50 000 000/8 = ~250MB  "divide by 8 to convert from bit to byte
```

Now we have to calculate the size of each column in the datastore by multiplying the number of unique values with the size of the field.

```
Name:    49 *  20 000 =   980 000
Surname: 49 * 100 000 = 4 900 000
Age:      1 *     128 =       128
Gender:   1 *       2 =         2
---------------------------------
Total:                  5 880 130  "~5MB
```

Now we know that the total size of the column store is ~255MB and the size of the uncompressed data is ~ 5000MB; All that remain is a simple division:

```
5000 / 255 = 19.6  "~20
```